# Question about LIST

Tags: c#, list

how are you please someone tell me why some of LISTs have useful methods like FIND , WHERE or ...
and some of them dont have these methods

and how can i use these methods when those LISTs  dont have

Comment: Lists in which Programming Language?

Comment: You should at least specify a programming language, not leave it up to us.

Comment: The capital letters of the type suggest Eiffel, but somehow I doubt it ... especially considering that methods are all lower-case there.

Comment: excuse me i forgot it 
my language is C#

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably missing references to [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx).

Add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

To your classes that don't have it, and add a reference to this assembly to projects that don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

List has number of methods like Find, FindAll, FindIndex etc. To work with delegates, for example:

```
var op in _opList.Find(op => op != null)
```